# .NET Core how to provide instance to Authorization Handler through Attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, authorization

We have a very complex authorization rules in our product. Due to this we rely heavily on a custom `AuthorizationHandler` pipeline within the .NET framework.

One problem we have right now is that we need to provide custom logic that will differ per endpoint in addition to already implemented `AuthorizationHandler`.

From reading documentation on:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-8.0
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/customizingauthorizationmiddlewareresponse?view=aspnetcore-8.0
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/dependencyinjection?view=aspnetcore-8.0

We are already using a custom `AuthorizationHandler` in combination with a custom 'PolicyProvider'. The custom authorization middleware is dealing with already executed response, so it is too late to perform any additional checks there.

The problem begins where we need to provide custom implementation in addition to existing custom `AuthorizationHandler` we have. Is there a way to provide an interface from an attribute or somehow pipe into authorization flow from `[Authorize]` attribute? where we can provide an interface or something to be able to get instance from DI container?

Comment: Why not describe a policy and add a policy handler?

Comment: @DanielA.White we could do this. But this would require all my teams to implement authorization pipeline, something that we wanted to avoid.  Instead the plan was  to provide them with an interface that would be resolved during runtime and executed after  general logic. 

But what you are suggesting does make sense for me. What do you think about Authentication Handlers, should those be implemented instead of whole policy? as it an extension to an existing policy